# How to execute a procedure from SQL Commander which has refcursor as a out parameter in db-visulizer

Tags: oracle11g, procedure, dbvisualizer

I have checked many SO Answers pertaining to this topic, but couldn't get the correct answer which is `DB-VISUALIZER` centric.This is the start and end of my procedure in DB-VIZ

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "pivot_view"( res out sys_refcursor )
dbms_output.put_line(query);
    open res for query;
end pivot_view;
```

To execute it from SQL Commander , I wrote :

`@ECHO ${rc ||32767||refcursor}$ @CALL pivot_view(rc); PRINT rc`   which doesn't seem to work.

How do I execute my compiled procedure

Comment: I don't know, I don't use *dbvisualizer*. But what I do know is that enclosing object names in Oracle into double quotes calls for trouble. I suggest you use `create or replace procedure pivot_view ...` and then try your SQL Commander again. BTW, saying that "it doesn't work", what exactly does that mean? Any error? If so, which one?

Comment: I don't know how to execute / call `refcursor` var type. There is no problem with `" "` in procedure name ,have run more than 20 procedure till now that way. I think only people who use 'DB VIZ` will have an idea about my question.

Comment: I believe so, yes; I hope you'll get the answer. Though, once again - using double quotes in Oracle is a bad idea. I'd recommend not to do that.

Comment: It's part od DBVIZ syntax,it's populated automatically,I don't have to write it

Comment: I suggest you open a support ticket with DbVisualizer using Help->Contact Support and we will help. /Roger @DbVisualizer